# Using JSON Access Strongly typed list in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i am developing a page in which on selection of dropdownlist the Json method gets call.

Below is my dropdownlist event:

```
function onChange(e) {

        alert(e.value);
        var id = e.value;
        //alert(e.val);
        $.post("/SysAdmin/UsersRole/Get",
            {
                Id: id
            },
                function (data, status) {
                    alert(data);
                });
    }
```

I am calling Get method of UsersRole controller which will return List of tree element.

The code of controller

```
public List<Tree> Get(int Id)
        {
            RolesToUserViewModel viewModel = UsersRole.GetRoleByUser(Id);
            return viewModel.Tree;
        }
```

i am getting data in viewModel object but not able to access that data in JS function.
How to access strongly typed object in JQuery?

Comment: is it a normal mvc controller method or asp.net webapi method?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid yes

Comment: yes for normal mvc method or web api method?

Comment: have u examined the response in firebug or fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can only use JSON Object to access the same.

Convert the returning Object into the JSONResult and change the type of the Action method to JSONResult.